# how to multiply two images in matrix multiplication manner in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, multiplication

I have two images A and B, each of mxm size. I want to multiply these images such that `C=AxB`.

So far I've found the `immultiply` function in MATLAB, but this function multiplies the corresponding bits of the images rather than performing matrix multiplication.

I have also tried `A.*B` but this also gives multiplication of corresponding bits. When I try `A*B` I get this message:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Integer data types are not fully supported for this operation.
At least one operand must be a scalar.
```

Comment: What can you tell us about the images? Are they binary? Grayscale? RGB? How do they end up in the workspace (i.e. how do you load them)?
Also, just to clarify - the result should also be of size m*m, right?

Comment: it is an RGB image which is loaded using imread. i have separated the R, G, B components of both the images and trying to multiply R component of one with R component of the other and so on... the resulting image should be of size mxm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the images into doubles before multiplying them.

Example:

multiplied = double(firstMat) * double(secondMat);

Comment: i have tried using double but when i used imshow to display the resultant image it gives a white image pixel values greater than 255. actually i am trying C=AxB, then i want to get A1=Cxinverse(B) so that A and A1 could be compared. they should be same according to matrix multiplication logic.

Comment: @SwatiGupta If `C` does make any graphical sense, you can normalize the result to `[0,1]` in order to display it with `imshow`. Should work for rgb image, as long as you normalize all 3 channels.

Comment: Why not just use `imagesc` instead of `imshow`?
Also please note that in MATLAB the recommended way to do matrix division is: `A1=C\B;`